# Passing and Comparing a controller in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form with 2 password inputs , one for password and the second to confirm it.

I was trying to do it like that :

```
final _passwordController = TextEditingController();

final _confirmpasswordController = TextEditingController();

String passwordInputValidator(TextEditingController _passwordController, value) {
if (value =!  _passwordController.text) {
return 'Password doesnt match';
}
}

MakeInput('Type your password', true,
                        nameInputValidator, _passwordController)),
               
                    MakeInput(
                        'Confirm Password',
                        true,
                        passwordInputValidator,
                        _confirmpasswordController)),

Widget MakeInput(label, obscureText, validator, controller) {
return Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      label,
      style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, color: Colors.white),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 5,
    ),
    TextFormField(
        obscureText: obscureText,
        controller: controller,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 12),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[800])),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[800])),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[800], width: 2.0),
            )),
        validator: validator),
```

This validator is the validator for the confirm password `TextField`.
So I tried passing the first password entered value as an argument in my validator and to compare it with my `value` which is the confirmed password.

I got this error in my function : `A negation operand must have a static type of 'bool'. Try changing the operand to the '!'`
I assume the error because of the dynamic type of the argument, but how to fix this error or even if there is any logic error .

Comment: welcome to SO. so what's your question?

Comment: I'm getting this error and the app is not launching .; A negation operand must have a static type of 'bool'.
Try changing the operand to the '!'

Comment: try by doing - if (value !=  _passwordController.text)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong comparison oparator =! use != instead

```
   String passwordInputValidator(
      TextEditingController _passwordController, value) {
    if (value != _passwordController.text) {
      return 'Password doesnt match';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.